# Search two columns in LINQ to SQL?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to make a simple search method using LINQ to SQL in Visual Studio. In my database, I have the fields "Firstname" and "Lastname", and my search string is "name". How can I make a simple LINQ query which searches both fields?

In plain SQL I would do something like this:

```sql
SELECT (Firstname + Lastname) as 'Fullname'
FROM   table
WHERE  Fullname LIKE '%searchstring%'
```

Comment: What did you try so far and why didn't it work?

Comment: I don't know how to join two fields in Linq, so haven't really tried anything yet.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The usual thing to do is this:

```
var users =
    from user in db.Users
    where user.FirstName.Contains(searchString) ||
        user.LastName.Contains(searchString)
    select user;
```

This however is not equivalent to your SQL query. The following is equivalent:

```
var users =
    from user in db.Users
    let fullName = user.FirstName + user.LastName
    where fullName.Contains(searchString)
    select user;
```

Comment: +1 for the answer in the second code box, but I am wondering about the code in the first box. I can't see that ever working. Example: 
searchString = "First Last"
wouldn't match if FirstName table contained "First" and LastName table contained "Last"

I guess you would need to split the string for that to work.

Comment: +1 Had never heard of the 'let' keyword, thanks for teaching me

Comment: @rasmusvhansen: The first query is indeed not the same as the second. In fact it is not really the 'usual thing to do'. The usual thing to do is to do a `string.Split(' ', searchString)` and combine those in the query, as can be seen in these answers: http://bit.ly/fKJCZT, http://bit.ly/hFS1nQ.

Answer (score 5):

```
var result = from p in db.Table
             let fullname = p.FirstName + " " + p.Lastname
             where fullname.Contains(searchString)
             select new { Fullname = fullname };
```

Comment: Hopefully more people will read further down as this solution will find Bob Smith when using the search strings "Bob", "Bob S" and "Bob Smith". Nice answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
// get all items from table where firstname like searchstring or lastname like searchstring
var result = from p in db.Table
             where (p.Firstname.Contains(searchString) || p.Lastname.Contains(searchString))
             select p;
```

Comment: That has nothing to do with the SQL in his question. Take my name for example. Searching for my full name would return me in his SQL but not in your query.