# LINQ concatenate 2 fields to search on

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, json, linq

I'm trying to concatenate two fields in LINQ so that I can then filter with a keyword. I found a question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676040/search-two-columns-in-linq-to-sql) that I thought was my answer, but I'm getting 0 records back for some reason. This is supposed to return a JSON result for an autocomplete textbox (it works when I don't concatenate fields).

Here's my code:

```
Function CostCodeList(ByVal term As String) As ActionResult

        Dim results = From c In db.ORG_CHART_V
                      Let Fullname = CStr(c.COSTCTR_CD & " - " & c.BREADCRUMB)
                      Where Fullname.ToUpper.Contains(CStr(term).ToUpper)
                      Order By Fullname
                      Select New With {.label = Fullname, .id = c.ORG_NODE_ID}

        Return Json(results.ToArray, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
  End Function
```

I'm also getting this error on the Return:

> Public member 'ToArray' on type 'DbQuery(Of VB$AnonymousType_3(Of
>   String,Integer))' not found.

Before trying to concatenate the two fields I was searching on them separately, successfully. But when I concatenate them, it seems like everything I try either gets me an error and/or zero records.

Here is a different function that does work:

```
Function RoleList(ByVal term As String) As ActionResult
        Dim list As New ArrayList
        Dim results As IQueryable(Of JOB_ROLE)

        If IsNumeric(term) Then
            results = From c In db.JOB_ROLE
                      Where CStr(c.JBROLE_NO).StartsWith(term)
        Else
            results = From c In db.JOB_ROLE
                      Where c.JOB_ROLE_NAME.ToUpper.Contains(CStr(term).ToUpper)
        End If

        results = results.OrderBy(Function(e) e.JOB_ROLE_NAME)

        For Each item In results
            list.Add(New With {.label = item.JOB_ROLE_NAME, .id = item.JOB_ROLE_ID})
        Next

        Return Json(list.ToArray, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
    End Function
```

Comment: Where is `list` declared? I don't see it before the `ToArray` call... I suspect you meant that to be `results`, but then presumably that means this *isn't* your real code, and there could be other differences. Also, is Option Strict on or not? I suspect not... and that that's the problem. Move the assignment to `results` to the same statement as the declaration (to allow type inference) and turn Option Strict on.

Comment: Yes, "list" should be "results". I changed that above. I moved the assignment like you suggested, but I still get an error on results.toArray. I'm unable to set Option Strict On as it causes many errors with other code in the file. I don't think this should be an issue since it was fine before I tried the concatenation.

Comment: You should fix the other code - Option Strict is rarely a good idea. I'm surprised it worked before - LINQ relies on extension methods, which rely on compile-time transformations... can you at least turn Option Infer On?

Comment: I think Jon means *Option Strict Off* is rarely a good idea.

Comment: I turned Option Infer On and am getting this error: A valid ResultType could not be inferred from the ResultTypes of the specified 'Then' expressions. To reiterate though, I'm not getting any results before the error. I'll post code that works above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the new function that works as intended:

```
    Function CostCodeList(ByVal term As String) As ActionResult
        Dim list As New ArrayList

        Dim results = db.ORG_CHART_V.Where(Function(e) (CStr(e.COSTCTR_CD) + " - " + e.BREADCRUMB).Contains(CStr(term).ToUpper)).OrderBy(Function(o) o.COSTCTR_CD)

        For Each item In results
            list.Add(New With {.label = item.COSTCTR_CD & " - " & item.BREADCRUMB, .id = item.ORG_NODE_ID})
        Next

        Return Json(list.ToArray, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
    End Function
```